# Does NSIS support IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, nsis

I have been assigned a task to modify existing installer so that it adds application on existing IIS website that the user will be able to select from a combo box. I found an IIS plugin for NSIS, but I cannot find any information on which versions of IIS are supported. Does NSIS (or rather [the plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisIIS_plug-in)) support adding applications to IIS sites on IIS7/IIS7.5/IIS8 natively (ie. without IIS6 compatibility tools installed)?

Answer (score 0):

Plugin support natively IIS6 infrastructure. It IS compatible with IIS7 and newers, but with some feature insufficienties as noted.

Source is freely available - you can help yourself and community and try to improve current feautres.

In my case I have this plugin fully self re-compiled and some bugs fixed for my employees pruposes therefore it is not sharable in public. Unfourtinately. :(

VBS, in fact, is not a solution - solution is to use appcmd and dism when needed ( MSDN got plenty of info ). :) I have found it is not so bad after all because some IIS7.x+ features still basically is just redesigned metabase compatibility layer, because the command line is fully yours controlled, not by some 3rd party plugins logic. ;)